# Perl executing an exe using system()?

Tags: perl

I could not able to run the `exe` using perl code.

```
my $XSD = "C:\\IParser\\Iparser\.exe --xsds \"$dir\\$out\_xsd\.xml\"";
system($XSD);
```

The above `$xsd` run in commend prompt it will execute fine. when I run through perl source code it shows error as

```
the handle is invalid
```

I don't no what is the problem behind this. Please help.

Comment: Try not using a backslash before the "." and the "_" character. Maybe try not using interpolation at all and concatenate the string, something like: `my $XSD = 'C:\IParser\Iparser.exe --xsds "' . $dir . '\' . $out . '_xsd.xml"';
system($XSD);` and see if you get a different result.

Comment: same error there no different result.

Comment: You might find it easier to use one of the built in parsing modules, such as `XML::LibXML`

Comment: Please provide the output obtained by adding `use Data::Dumper; { local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($XSD)); }`

Comment: sorry for late reply @ikegami after adding your code i got the outputpath.       $VAR1 = "C:\\IParser\\Iparser.exe --xsds \"C:\\itools\\WMS\\TandF-Journals\\Tools\\Fold_tandf\\cats_xsd.xml\"";

Comment: I was looking for newlines or something like that.  No such problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of closed handles to STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR (or any of them). Most probably if you run this as a daemon or from service.

Try opening the standard handles before running the process (assuming you're on windows according to path):

```
open(STDIN, "<NUL");
open(STDOUT, ">NUL");
open(STDERR, ">NUL");
```